# What is the /~ file on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, file

In the root directory of my Mac (10.10.4) I see a file named just `~` (tilde):

```
$ ls -l /~
-rw-------  2 root  wheel  2187264 Mar 23 22:33 /~
```

`file` just reports it as "data". For reference, here are the first 256 bytes as seen through `xxd`:

```
0000000: d0fa d0da 0010 0000 2800 0000 9002 0000  ........(.......
0000010: 1b00 0000 0000 0000 0c00 0000 2c00 0000  ............,...
0000020: ca02 0000 0000 0000 0e00 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000030: 3c63 6174 616c 6f67 3e00 0000 0b00 0000  <catalog>.......
0000040: 0010 0000 5374 7269 6e67 0000 0a00 0000  ....String......
0000050: 0010 0400 4172 7261 7900 0000 0b00 0000  ....Array.......
0000060: 0090 0500 4275 6e64 6c65 0000 0a00 0000  ....Bundle......
0000070: 0010 0700 436c 6169 6d00 0000 0c00 0000  ....Claim.......
0000080: 0090 0800 5365 7276 6963 6500 0900 0000  ....Service.....
0000090: 00a0 0800 5479 7065 0000 0000 0f00 0000  ....Type........
00000a0: 00a0 0900 5554 4942 696e 6469 6e67 0000  ....UTIBinding..
00000b0: 1500 0000 0020 0a00 4578 7465 6e73 696f  ..... ..Extensio
00000c0: 6e42 696e 6469 6e67 0000 0000 1200 0000  nBinding........
00000d0: 00a0 0a00 4f53 5479 7065 4269 6e64 696e  ....OSTypeBindin
00000e0: 6700 0000 1000 0000 00e0 0a00 4d49 4d45  g...........MIME
00000f0: 4269 6e64 696e 6700 1800 0000 0000 0b00  Binding.........
```

It appears to be full of file paths and extensions, along with a lot more filesystem data. Is this a standard file to have on OS X, and if so what is its purpose? If it's not a standard file, any ideas of what created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an unnecessary file. You can simply delete it if no process is currently using it. This question was already answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/172256/tilde-file-in-macintosh-directory).